# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
(function(){

    var Person = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    };

    Person.prototype.getName(){
        return this.name;
    };

    var arif = new Person("Arif");

    console.log(arif.getName());

})();
```

I am receiving the error below for this code. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set the `getName()` function to `return this.name;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```js
(function(){

    var Person = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    };

    Person.prototype.getName = function(){
        return this.name;
    };

    var arif = new Person("Arif");

    console.log(arif.getName());

})();
```

Basically, you need to define "getName" on the prototype line, and the syntax you were using on the line with .prototype was trying to call it (before it was defined).

Comment: @jsve I down voted because it doesn't properly compile.

Comment: @Wyatt it works for me (I copied and pasted it into my browser console).

Comment: @Wyatt Actually it does.